What is this novel about magic in York?
I read this Fantasy novel about 20 years ago.
What I remember most vividly is that it takes place (or at least, it begins) in York, and it is about magic. I do remember that much because I read it shortly after a trip to England I took with my family, and while staying in York we heard a lot about the magical tradition there.
In this novel there is a society of magicians (wizards ?) in York. But they mostly discuss about magic, they don't practice it. One day a new magician arrives in York, joins this society and to the disapproval of everyone else, he starts suggesting that they should actually do some magic. This proposal creates a lot of problems, about which I don't remember any details at all.

+1 I am voting to close because this appears to be a duplicate of Book about leprechauns, a war between two warlocks, and candles

This is Jonathan Strange & Mr Norrell by Susanna Clarke.

The novel opens in 1806 in northern England with The Learned Society of York Magicians, whose members are "theoretical magicians" who study magical texts and history, after the decline of magic in England several hundred years earlier. The group is stunned to learn of a "practical magician", Mr Gilbert Norrell. Norrell proves his skill as a magician by making the statues in York Cathedral speak, thereafter compelling the society to disband. John Childermass, Mr Norrell's servant, convinces a member of the group, John Segundus, to write about the event for the London newspapers.

